# Pascal read int into array

Tags: arrays, user-input, pascal

I am just learning Pascal at school and have run into a weird problem in my assignment.

What I need to do is create two arrays and then read in integers for the first array until 10 numbers are read or a negative number is read, then move on to the second array with the same rules.

I have that all working fine except for the first number in the second array is always messed up. -1 seems to always be copied to array 2 index 1.

I can't give away to much code because this is an assignment but it is something like this:

```
while input >= 0 and index < 10 do
    begin
    read(input);
    array1[index] := input;
        index++
    end;

input:= 0; //to reset it

another while loop but for list2...
```

If I input for array1 1, 2, 3, -1 and array2 1, 2, 3, 4, -1 my output would be something like:

```
list 1: 1 list 2: -1
list 1: 2 list 2: 2
list 1: 3 list 2: 3
list 1: -1 list 2: 4
```

Does this make sense? I just need a little help understand why this is happening, I'm stuck here.

Comment: You want to necessarily read 10 integers (positive and negative) in the two arrays or the stop condition is a negative number?

Comment: I want to only read 10 positive ints, and stop when 10 are read or when the first negative int is read.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you *gave away* that would cause this behavior. The only thing I notice is that you're incrementing some 'index' in the while loop but then testing the terminating while condition against some 'inputs'. BTW, is there really a pascal compiler that would compile this code?

Comment: This isn't my real code, so it wont compile.

Comment: You're expecting someone to point an error in code that he cannot see. Good luck with that..

Comment: @Sam: Then post your real code. As Sertac said, you're expecting us to guess at what might be wrong based on nonsense you posted as a sample. If you want help, provide actual information. If you don't care enough about your question to do that, you might as well not ask for help in the first place. :-) Try going to your doctor and saying "I have a sore on my leg that looks something like this. What's wrong?" and hand him/her a pencil drawing on a piece of paper, and see if you get a diagnosis and treatment.

Comment: You should reset your index variable along with input, because you are apparently using them for the second list.

Answer (score 1):

As comments to your question have pointed out, it's a bit difficult to find what's wrong when almost certainly the problem is with the code that you *didn't* post. That being said, however, there are a few visible problems

1. Read 'input' *before* the 'while' loop. Entering the 'while' loop is dependent on the initial value of 'input'; I imagine that you are presuming that its initial value is 0, but it could be some garbage number with a negative value.
2. 'index++' is not Pascal syntax, but C. This should be 'inc (index)'.
3. Instead of writing 'input:= 0' after the first loop, this should be 'index:= 0'.

I imagine that the code, after the first 'while' loop should be

```
index:= 0;
readln (input);
while (input >= 0) and (index < 10) do
 begin
  inc (index);
  array2[index]:= input;
  readln (input) // there is no need for a semicolon before 'end'!
 end;
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you refusing to put a semicolon before an end?

Comment: There is no need to put a semicolon there; a semicolon is a statement separator and not a statement 'concluder'.

Comment: Doesn't that get back to you when you want to add more statements after the previously last one? Not judging or anything, just curious.

Comment: Possibly, but in this case, 'readln (input)' *has* to be the last statement in the 'while' block.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you selectively decide whether to put the semicolon or not depending on whether the last statement may change or not... seems a bit inconsistent, no? I mean, I don't know..